# Checking if a list contains the-same item specific amount times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a list in which I put gameObjects with specific tag and name. I need to know if the list contains multiple copies of the same object.

The solution I figured out is probably too complicated and not good but here it is:

Let's say I need to know whether a list contains 3 copies of this game Object. I would have a for loop where I would be checking if the list contains this object (name, tag etc) and I would put this object into a temp variable and than I would destroy (remove) this object from the list and followed on by checking if the list contains another and 3th gameObject.

All would be assigned to unique variables and if I would, for example, find only 2 copies I would add those destroyed objects back to the list and, of course, stopped the loop.

I hope this is understandable

Comment: First define "same" (equality). Do you mean reference equality (default) or value equality (default for value types)? Also if they are "the same type", why not just identify them based on their subclass?

Comment: They are copies of one prefab, so they have same values, name and tag

Comment: How often do you want/have to do this checking?

Comment: Quite frequently, maybe every few seconds even less. I know this would be quite performance heavy

Comment: And how about just prevent Duplicates to come into the list in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky but can be done with a `Dictionary` while looping over that `List`.

This is what to do:

**1**.Create `Dictionary` to hold the objects. The **key** should be the type of Object. In my case, I will use `GameObject`. The **value** should be an `int`. That int will represent the number of times that `GameObject` appeared in the `List`.

**2**.Loop over that List that contains all the GameObjects to check.

**3**.In each loop, check if the Object from the current loop in **#2** exist in the dictionary.

If it exist in the dictionary, *retrieve the value then increment it by `1`*. If it does not exist in the dictionary, *add that current GameObject to the dictionary with the value of `1`*.

**4**.Finally, check if we have reached that x amount in the dictionary by comparing your target specific amount(`3`) with the value from the dictionary. Break out of the loop this is true otherwise continue the loop until the end.

Everything above converted into functions. See comments for more info:

```
bool listConstainsSpecificObjCount(List<GameObject> targetObjList, GameObject targetObj, int appearedCount)
{
    bool containsSpecificObjCount = false;

    //1 Dictionary to hold the object found in each loop
    Dictionary<GameObject, int> tempDic = new Dictionary<GameObject, int>();

    //2 Loop over the targetObjList
    for (int i = 0; i < targetObjList.Count; i++)
    {
        //Current Object in the Loop
        GameObject currentDicObj = targetObjList[i];

        int dicResult = 0;

        //3 Check if the Object from the current loop exist in the dictionary
        if (tempDic.TryGetValue(currentDicObj, out dicResult))
        {
            //It exists, increment the count by 1
            dicResult++;

            //Update data/value in the existing Dictionary
            tempDic[currentDicObj] = dicResult;
        }
        else
        {
            //Use 1 for the value because we are about to add it to the Dictionary
            dicResult = 1;

            //Add current Object to the Dictionary for the first time
            tempDic.Add(currentDicObj, dicResult);
        }

        //4 Check if we have reached that x amount in the dictionray then break out of the loop
        if (dicResult >= appearedCount)
        {
            containsSpecificObjCount = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return containsSpecificObjCount;
}
```

**USAGE**:

```
//The list of the Objects to check if they appeared x amount of time
public List<GameObject> testList;
//The specific Object to check 
public GameObject objToCheck;
//The X amount of time it should check if it appeared
int specificCount = 3;

void Start()
{
    bool result = listConstainsSpecificObjCount(testList, objToCheck, specificCount);
    Debug.Log(result);
}
```

If you want to improve this, move `Dictionary<GameObject, int> tempDic = new Dictionary<GameObject, int>();` outside of that function so that new `Dictionary` is **not** created each time it is called. Clear the dictionary in the beginning of that function with `tempDic.Clear();`.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I have been looking for

Comment: You are welcome. I used `GameObject` as the key but you can always change that to any type of Object like `Rigidbody` or so.